# Jira ServiceDesk API - attachments endpoints not available

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to set up JIRA servicedesk API with my application. All is going well so far, but I would like the ability to attach a file to a newly created request.

According to the documentation (https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-servicedesk/REST/server) this is done through two endpoints:

- /servicedesk/{serviceDeskId}/attachTemporaryFile
- /request/{requestIDorCode}/attachment

However, attempting to access either of these endpoints returns 404. They are marked as experimental on the documentation, so I wonder if they have been removed and no one has updated the docs? Is this the case? If so, is there any other way I can go about adding an attachment to a ticket? If not... well, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

This is how I am attaching the file to the curl request:

```
$curlFile = new \CURLFile($data['file']);
$curlFile->setPostFilename('TEST');
$data['file'] = $curlFile;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

This is my API call (with a library):

```
$this->api(
            static::REQUEST_POST,
            "servicedesk/{$this->serviceDeskId}/attachTemporaryFile",
            [
                'file' => $file->getRealPath(),
                'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
            ],
            true,
            true
        )
```

The library prepends the jira server URL, obviously. Through debugging, the endpoint and data format seems 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation (https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-servicedesk/REST/server):

> Methods marked as EXPERIMENTAL may change without notice. We are looking for your feedback for these methods. **To use experimental methods, you must set this header in your requests: X-ExperimentalApi : true.** This indicates that you are opting into the experimental preview. Once a resource or method moves out of the experimental phase, then this header will no longer be required nor checked.

Did you add this header to your request to the following links:

- https://yourinstance.com/rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/{serviceDeskId}/attachTemporaryFile
- https://yourinstance.com/rest/servicedeskapi/request/{requestIDorCode}/attachment

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I have added the flag, all the other experimental endpoints work.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code (how the request is configured)? It may help us to pin point the issue.

Comment: Btw, I just remark that you need to specify the following links:
`POST /rest/servicedeskapi/request/{issueIdOrKey}/attachment` and 
`POST /rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/{serviceDeskId}/attachTemporaryFile`. Did you put `/rest/servicedeskapi/` in your URL and use a `POST` method?

Comment: Since it's an experimental method and the documentation points to the latest version of the API, maybe your version is not up-to-date to have these calls. I suggest that you validate your Service Desk version with Atlassian.